# Double buffering to end flickering in C

Tags: c, graphic, doublebuffered

I know it should be something very simple but really for some reason I can't get the hang of it.
I searched and searched and all I could under stand is that we put the bits in a `2D array` then change the graphical pointer to that array which would make the screen change instantly rather than drawing it bit by bit.

I got no idea about what a `graphic pointer` is  or how am I supposed to put the bits in the array to be specific my problem is how to write the right code for that.

I am using `Windows 7 and VS2012` as a compiler 
and I have to use graphic.h for my project cues it's something I gotta do for my programming class .

Comment: Which language you are using and how many bits is your operating system ?

Comment: What's `graphic.h`? Perhaps add a link to referece doc, to make it explicit what library you are referring to...

Comment: Double buffering usually include a HW-synchronized access to the buffers. You draw the next graphic to one buffer while the other is still displayed. When you're done with drawing you tell the graphic engine that it shall use the buffer with new content. The switch will take place when it doesn't hurd, preferable in an interrupt service routine. But this highly depends on your environment. I can't say how you would do this in Win7 except that you prepare the graphic before you tell the API that you've completed.

Comment: it's the known library graphics.h and i am using C language as stated in the title. :)